# "Def create" manually rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

Is there any way on manually doing the "create" function?
I have an scaffold, (model/controller/view), so what I want to do is to change a little bit the parameters that the user gave me.

```
 def create

  @meme = Meme.new(params[:meme])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @meme.save
      format.html { redirect_to @meme, notice: 'Meme was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @meme, status: :created, location: @meme }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @meme.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way of doing something like:

```
def create

  @meme = Meme.new
  @meme.name = params([:name])
  @meme.id = params([:id])
  @meme.url = @meme.name+@meme.id 




  respond_to do |format|
    if @meme.save
      format.html { redirect_to @meme, notice: 'Meme was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @meme, status: :created, location: @meme }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @meme.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

So as you can see in the last example I want to save a URL concatenating the name and the id,
is there any way of achieving this from the controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are looking for is kind of a combination of both of your samples:

```
def create

  @meme = Meme.new(params[:meme])
  @meme.url = "#{@meme.name}-#{@meme.id}" 

  respond_to do |format|
    if @meme.save
      format.html { redirect_to @meme, notice: 'Meme was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @meme, status: :created, location: @meme }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @meme.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I threw in a dash between the name and the id just for kicks.

You might also want to think about doing this in a `before_save` hook inside the Meme model, that would be a cleaner solution than having it in the controller. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked like a charm, hehe but you got me thinking if the proper method is doing it in the model, how can I handle the data in the model, i tried something like this `def before_save(model)
    @meme.url ="ok"
  end `

Comment: @Mau: `before_save` is a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), not a method name. You'd want `before_save :set_url` and then `def set_url...` to set the URL.

Comment: BTW, you *really* should use id-name instead of name-id. Will make everything better (Meme.find("3-nhocki") == Meme.find(3) ) so scaffold actions will work anyway.